# How can I introspect a Java class's Jackson PropertyNamingStrategy when it is explicitly set by @JsonNaming?

Tags: java, jackson

I have some code which reads rows from a database and using Jackson ObjectMapper to convert them to objects. I am trying to make this as generic as possible, to serve as a library function.

For some particular object classes, the PropertyNamingStrategy is set explicitly via the @JsonNaming annotation to something other than how my row schema is defined (just the name casing is different, conceptually the names and data are the same).

I can use an intermediate library to convert the expected property names after I get them from the row schema to how the @JsonNaming annotation defines them. But that is very specific to one class.

Is there a way I can introspect a class type to find out what its PropertyNamingStrategy is? Or use ObjectMappper (or another Jackson utility) to find out, prior to doing the actual deserialization? That way my caller would not need to know or care about this when using my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can introspect a class type to find out what its
> PropertyNamingStrategy is?

Yes, you can use the the [`SerializationConfig#introspectClassAnnotations`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationConfig.html) method that returns a [`BeanDescription`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/BeanDescription.html), gets its info and create an `AnnotatedClass` that will be inspected by the `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` instance like below:

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.KebabCaseStrategy.class)
public class MyClass {}

AnnotatedClass acl = mapper.getSerializationConfig()
                .introspectClassAnnotations(MyClass.class)
                .getClassInfo();
JacksonAnnotationIntrospector jai = new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector();
//in this case it will prints class
//com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy$KebabCaseStrategy
//In case of no annotation over the class the value will be null
System.out.println(jai.findNamingStrategy(acl));
```